# How to set multiple .textcontents to one click event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

Im displaying a button with the text "Drive" on load, that starts a function which lets the wheels of a car rotate. The moment you click on the "Drive" button another button shows up with the text "Stop". 
Im setting all the .textContent of the buttons in javascript. 
I want the first time you click the "Drive" button, the textContent to change to "faster", and if you click it after that the textContent to be "Faster!!". 
If you are done driving you can press the "Stop" button to stop the wheels from rotating. 
The "Stop" button will disappear and set the "Faster!!" button, back to "Drive".

So far everything is working fine, but only for the first time.. After that it sets the "Faster" text back to "Drive", but when I click it, it right away goes to "Faster!!", skipping the "faster" content.

I think something must be going wrong here:

```
  // Set text button to faster
  driveXcar.textContent = "faster";


  driveXcar.onclick = function() {
    driveXcar.textContent = "Faster!!";
  }
```

I cant get it to work.

Code below:

```
// DRIVE BUTTON
let driveXcar = document.getElementById("drive");
driveXcar.addEventListener('click', driveCar);
driveXcar.textContent = "Drive";

//STOP BUTTON
let stopXcar = document.getElementById("stop");
stopXcar.style.display = "none";
stopXcar.textContent = "Stop";

let i = 0;

function driveCar() {
  // Display stop button on click drive
  document.getElementById("stop").style.display = "block";

    let start = setInterval(function () {
    i += 2;

    backLines.forEach(line => {
      line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ", 85, 180)");
      }),
      frontLines.forEach(line => {
        line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ", 336, 180)");
      }),
      backLinesHatchback.forEach(line => {
        line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ", 100, 180)");
      })
  }, 10);

  // Set text button to faster
  driveXcar.textContent = "faster";

  driveXcar.onclick = function() {
    driveXcar.textContent = "Faster!!";
  }


  // Add event listener to stop button
  stopXcar.addEventListener('click', stopCar);

  function stopCar() {
    clearInterval(start);
    driveXcar.textContent = "Drive";
    stopXcar.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Nesting event listeners is a bad practice. Why do you need such thing at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful when nesting event listeners, in your case, you are adding a new event listener on the stop button every time the drive button is pressed which is bad. Nesting event listeners is considered bad practice and should be avoided when possible. I have made a possible solution and you can check it on this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qahumegace/edit?html,js,output).

```
let state = 'stop'; // 'stop' | 'faster' | 'Faster!!'
let driveXcar = initDriveCar();
let stopXcar = initStopCar();
let start;

function initDriveCar() {
  let driveXcar = document.getElementById("drive");
  driveXcar.addEventListener('click', driveCar);
  driveXcar.textContent = "Drive";
  return driveXcar;
}

function initStopCar() {
  let stopXcar = document.getElementById("stop");
  stopXcar.addEventListener('click', stopCar);
  stopXcar.style.display = "none";
  stopXcar.textContent = "Stop";
  return stopXcar;
}

function driveCar() {
  // Display stop button on click drive
  stopXcar.style.display = "block";

  if (start) {
    clearInterval(start);
  }

  start = setInterval(function () {
    // your logic
  }, 10);

  state = getNextState(state, 'drive');
  if (state === 'faster') {
    driveXcar.textContent = "faster";
  }
  else {
    driveXcar.textContent = "Faster!!";
  }
}

function stopCar() {
  clearInterval(start);
  driveXcar.textContent = "Drive";
  stopXcar.style.display = "none";
  state = getNextState(state, 'stop')
}

function getNextState(state, buttonClicked) {
  if (state === 'stop' && buttonClicked === 'drive') {
    return 'faster';
  }
  else if (state === 'faster' && buttonClicked === 'drive') {
    return 'Faster!!';
  }
  else if (state === 'Faster!!' && buttonClicked === 'drive') {
    return 'Faster!!';
  } // include more conditions if necessary
  else {
    return 'stop';
  }
}
```

I have split the code into smaller chunks so it is easier to read and understand but I tried to follow the same logic of yours, however I have added a state property to help you keep track of the car state.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this. I will definately avoid nesting event listeners in my future code. Going to edit my code.

Comment: I have edited my code, but I still get a problem. When I click drive one time it starts the function, and changes the textContent to faster. 
If I click stop, the function stops and everything is fine. 
But if I click the drive button a couple times to make it go faster and then press stop it wont stop. 
So again, I have putted the stop function back in the drive function, and that actually makes it stop. 
I have logged (start) and everytime you press drive, it counts +1, when you click stop it just stops the current count. 
Only when I put it in the function it stops completely..

Comment: I have edited the code to fix some issues, check it out. About the `start` variable, you are correct, I forgot to cancel the current interval before creating a new one, this is been taken care of on the edit.